# Phonegap GPS tracking stops inserting to sqlite database after 30 seconds

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, cordova, gps

I am having an issue storing my location data for my journey tracking app. I am using both the accelerometer and GPS location in my app. All the data is being stored in the phones sqlite database. The sampling rate for the accelerometer is 25ms and 3000ms for the GPS. So for every 120 acceleromter readings I put into the database there is one GPS reading inserted.

This is working perfectly for about 30 seconds then the app strangely stops adding the GPS readings but it continues to add the accelerometer readings.

Below is my watch function that runs every 3 seconds taking readings from the GPS. The reason I am using this is because I was having issues previously with watch function for the plugin.

SetupWatch Function code:

```
var activeWatch=null;
// sets up the interval at the specified frequency
function setupWatch(freq) {
    activeWatch = setInterval(watchLocation, freq);

}

// stop watching

function logout() {
    clearInterval(activeWatch);
}
```

watch function code:

```
function watchLocation() {
    var gcp = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
           // Success
        function(position){
            newlongitude = position.coords.longitude;
            //alert("New "+newlongitude)
            newlatitude = position.coords.latitude;
            newSpeed = position.coords.speed;
            //alert(position.coords.speed);
            var timestamp = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
            //alert(timestamp);

            insertDB(track_id, newlongitude,newlatitude,newSpeed,timestamp,row);
            row+=120;
        },

        // Error
        function(error){
            alert(error.message);
        }, {
                enableHighAccuracy: true
            });

}
```

Below is the function I use to insert the GPS readings into my database. I use the sql update statement to update the row already created from the accelerometer reading with the GPS reading and the current compass heading direction.

InsertDB function code:

```
function insertDB(trackID, longi,lat,speed, time,arow){
    //alert(Longi + " " + Lat);

    watch_Comp = navigator.compass.getCurrentHeading(onSuccess, onError,compassOptions);

        function onSuccess(heading) {
                    newDir = heading.magneticHeading;
                    //alert(newDir);
                    if(arow===0){
                    arow=1;
                    }
                    //alert("update row "+arow);

                    db.transaction(function(tx){
                    tx.executeSql('UPDATE DEMO SET longitude = '+'\''+longi+'\''+', latitude = '+'\''+lat+'\''+
                                ', speed = '+'\''+speed+'\''+ ', time = '+'\''+time+'\''+', direction = '+'\''+newDir+'\''+
                                ' WHERE uniqueID = ' + '\''+arow+'\'');
                    }, errorCB);

                };

                function onError(error) {
                    alert('CompassError: ' + error.code);
                };

                var compassOptions = {
                    frequency: 3000
                };
```

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this to happen?

Comment: `row+=120` ? `arow=1` ?

Comment: `So for every 120 acceleromter readings I put into the database there is one GPS reading inserted.`. Hard to believe. That's what you want. There could only be 100. Or 25. Or one.

Comment: @greenapps 'arow' is just what I called it in the insertDB function but it could be called row and it would work perfectly as it is just the name of the parameter within that function I'm still passing row to it. Sorry I probably didn't explain that well, yes every 120 accelerometer readings a GPS reading is inserted because each accelerometer reading occurs every 25ms. 120 x 25 = 3000ms (3 seconds).

Comment: @greenapps If you were wondering why I changed 'arow' =1 if arow=0 because I'm updating the GPS rows by the uniqueID created by the sqlite database and this starts at 1 not 0. After the first GPS insertion at 1 the rest are be adding at iterations of 120 eg Update row 1,120,240 etc.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The reason it stopped updating the GPS data is because the row it was trying to update was not created yet. When I start tracking my journey I start the accelerometer watch first and it begins to insert the accelerometer readings. I then start the GPS watch which updates the accelerometer rows that have been created with the GPS readings.

The problem was that the accelerometer watch has to do so many inserts to the database it is a bit slower over the 3 seconds so eventually the GPS watch catches up with it and tries to update a row that hasn't been created. Once the GPS watch passes the accelerometer watch I am unable to store the GPS readings.

A solution to this is to slow the GPS watch to 3.5 seconds sampling rate or change it from 'updating' the acceleromter rows to an 'insert'. Although if it is changed to an insert there will be double rows at every three second marker in the database. This is why I changed it to update in the first place.

Comment: `I figured it out.` ?   `because the row it was trying to update was not created yet`. Yes that i was telling you. But you did not understand!?

Comment: @greenapps No from reading your comments I believe you thought there was an issue with the row variable. This was not the issue the problem is that the delay from all the accelerometer data 'inserts' is slightly exceeding 3 seconds so eventually my GPS data 'updates' catches up and passes the accelerometer data that is being inserted. Once it passes it there is no row created for the GPS data to 'update'. It is hard to explain I'm not sure if you understand me.

Comment: I understood that that was the problem right from the beginning and tried to tell you. You should have understood that by now. Read my second comment. It tells all. You cannot update row 120 if only 100 exist i wrote.

Comment: @greenapps where are you pulling 100 out of? I don't think you understand the issue